# i want to implement request-reply pattern using kafkajs in typescript. How can i implement that?

Tags: node.js, typescript, apache-kafka

I am new with kafka and i want to achieve request reply pattern using kafkajs in typescript i had implemented that in a very rough way to make it work only but the consumer inside producers which waits for the reply are taking too much time to start and and a consumer for that particular producer is also starting very slowly. so is there anyway to fix that and implement request-response properly

```
//Code for Producer

import { Kafka, KafkaConfig, EachMessagePayload } from 'kafkajs';

const kafkaConfig: KafkaConfig = { brokers: ['127.0.0.1:9092'] };
const kafka = new Kafka(kafkaConfig);

const producer = kafka.producer();
let correlation = 0;

export const authentication = async (message: string) => {
  const correlationId = (correlation++).toString();
  
  try {
    await producer.connect();
    await producer.send({
      topic: 'token-validation',
      messages: [
        {
          value: message,
          headers: {
            'correlation-id': correlationId,
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    const consumer = kafka.consumer({ groupId: 'token-response' });

    await consumer.connect();
    await consumer.subscribe({ topic: 'token-response', fromBeginning: true });

    await consumer.run({
      eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }: EachMessagePayload) => {
        const rCorrelationId = message.headers?.['correlation-id']?.toString();
        console.log({rCorrelationId: rCorrelationId})
        if (rCorrelationId === correlationId) {
          const value = message.value?.toString();
          console.log(`Received message on topic ${topic}, partition ${partition}, correlation ID ${correlationId}, message: ${value}`);
        }
      },
    });

    // await consumer.disconnect();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during Kafka processing:', error);
  } finally {
    await producer.disconnect();
  }
};
```

//Code for Consumer

```
import { Kafka, Consumer, EachMessagePayload } from 'kafkajs';

const kafka = new Kafka({ brokers: ['127.0.0.1:9092'] });
const consumer = kafka.consumer({ groupId: "test-group" }); // Set your consumer group

export const testWorker = async () => {
  await consumer.connect();
  await consumer.subscribe({ topic: 'token-validation', fromBeginning: true }); // Subscribe to the same topic used by the producer

  await consumer.run({
    eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }: EachMessagePayload) => {
      const correlationId = message.headers?.['correlation-id'];
      const value1 = message.value?.toString();
      console.log(`Received message on topic ${topic}, partition ${partition}, correlation ID ${correlationId}, message: ${value1}`);
      
      const producer = kafka.producer();
      await producer.connect();

      const rmessage = `Response to ${value1}`;
      await producer.send({
        topic: 'token-response',
        messages: [
          { value: rmessage, headers: {
            'correlation-id': correlationId,
          }},
        ],
      });
      console.log(`Response sent for correlationId ${correlationId}`)
      await producer.disconnect();

      // Now you can process the message and use the correlation ID as needed
    },
  });
};
```

any hints to make it work as expected and also is there any other way to communicate between the microservices other than messagingqueue and api.
i want to implement token validation from 1 service to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Kafka is not a good tool for request-reply workflows.

Since you tagged the question originally with [[image]aws-lambda](/questions/tagged/aws-lambda), instead, you'd create a Lambda that is triggered from Kafka events, directly, not write any consumer code on your own. That lambda could do anything, including using another Kafka producer client.